# Can you have an array as one value within an array?

Tags: php

Is there any way to display an array as a value of one array value only.

For example,

```
Array:
[1] = some value
[2] = an array of values
[3] = some value
```

---

```
$main_array = array(
    [] => 11,
    [] => 22,
    [] => $sub_array = array([] => a, [] => b, [] => c,);
    [] => 44,
);
var_dump($main_array);
```

Returns parse error -> this part is invalid:

```
[] => $sub_array = array([] => a, [] => b, [] => c,);
```

Comment: Okay, good luck with that, now what is your question for us?

Comment: If I make an array and try to assign multiple values to one of the values it errors out... is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything? Add it! if it shows an error, add it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code to declare the `$main_array` array is riddled with syntax errors:

1. You can't use an array of any kind as a key in an associative array. [PHP: Can an array have an array as a key in a key-value pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504771/3088508)
2. The `$sub_array` inside `$main_array` needs to use quotes around [string values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) like this: `['a', 'b', 'c']`.
3. You absolutely can't separate elements of an array with a semicolon `;` Use a comma `,`

I think you want a [multidimensional array](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_arrays_multi.asp):

> A multidimensional array is an array containing one or more arrays.

So, to write your array in that format:

```
$main_array = [
    11,
    22,
    [
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
    ],
    44,
];
```